# Form Sending Email but Showing blank Page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have my homepage on a testing server. When I submit the form, the page shows a blank page, BUT it is also sending the email.

The second problem is, that the checkbox values are not shown in the email, I don't think they are read by the php-file...

My button has the proper type (submit), I don't have any spelling mistakes in the names...And I am not so into php, therefore I really don't know, what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML-Code

```
<form action="contact.php" id="form" method="post" name="send">
<span class="input input--kuro">


<div class="row">
<h3 class="big-blue">Kontaktformular</h3>
<h2 class="small-grey">Bitte füllen Sie das Formular aus, damit wir Ihnen ein individuelles Angebot zukommen lassen können.</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="row">
<div class="input-wrapper col-md-4 col-centered">
<input  class="requiredField name subscribe-requiredField input__field input__field--kuro" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name">
<label class="input__label input__label--kuro" for="subscribe-email">
<span class="mail input__label-content input__label-content--kuro">Name</span>
</label> 
</div>


<div class="input-wrapper col-md-4 col-centered">
<input  class="requiredField subscribe-requiredField input__field input__field--kuro" type="text" name="firma" placeholder="Firma" id="firma">
<label class="input__label input__label--kuro" for="subscribe-email">
<span class="mail input__label-content input__label-content--kuro">Firma</span>
</label> 
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="input-wrapper col-md-4 col-centered">
<input  class="requiredField email subscribe-requiredField input__field input__field--kuro" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email">
<label class="input__label input__label--kuro" for="subscribe-email">
<span class="mail input__label-content input__label-content--kuro">Email</span>
</label> 
</div>

<div class="input-wrapper col-md-4 col-centered">
<input  class="requiredField subscribe-requiredField input__field input__field--kuro" type="text" name="number" placeholder="Telefonnummer" id="number">
<label class="input__label input__label--kuro" for="subscribe-email">
<span class="mail input__label-content input__label-content--kuro">Telefonnummer</span>
</label> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</ul>
<li><button class="submit-button" id="submit" type="submit">Senden</button></li>
<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary added-btn" title="Zur Übersicht." id="gesamt-zurueck" name="submit-clear" >Zurück zur Übersicht</button></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </span>

 <div class="hidden">
 <ul class="checker-wrap">
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="0" value="Zielgruppendefinition" class="0 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="1" value="Namensfindung & Logoentwicklung" class="1 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="2" value="Exposé" class="2 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="3" value="Textdesign" class="3 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="4" value="Anzeigenkampagnen" class="4 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="5" value="Außenwerbung" class="5 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="6" value="Bautafelgestaltung" class="6 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="8" value="Website" class="8 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="9" value="Social Media" class="9 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="10" value="Digitale Präsentation" class="10 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" id="11" value="Innenvisualisierungen" class="11 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="14" value="Außenvisualisierungen" class="11 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="12" value="Virtuelle Begehung" class="12 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="13" value="Augmented Reality" class="13 checker" name="checkbox-group[]"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The PHP-file Code:

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'schroeder@exposedesign.de';
if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||
empty($_POST['email']) ||
empty($_POST['number']) ||
empty($_POST['firma']))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: Required Field";
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$firma = $_POST['firma'];
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox-group'];




if (!eregi(
"^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", 
$email))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: Invalid Email Address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Angebot angefordert";
$email_body = "\n Name: $name \n Email: $email \n Firma: $firma \n Telefon: \n $number";
$headers = "From: $email";
$leistungen = "\n Gewählte Leistungen: $checkbox";

mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers, $leistungen);
}
?>
```

The jQuery Code:

```
// contact form
    $("form#form").submit(function() {
        $("form#form .error").remove();
        var s = !1;
        if ($(".requiredField").each(function() {
            if ("" === jQuery.trim($(this).val())) {
                $(this).prev("label").text(), $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">This field is required</span>'), $(this).addClass(
                "inputError"), s = !0;
                }
            else if ($(this).hasClass("email")) {
                var r = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                r.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val())) || ($(this).prev("label").text(), $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">Invalid email address</span>'), $(
                    this).addClass("inputError"), s = !0);
            }
        }), !s) {
            $("form#form input.submit").fadeOut("normal", function() {
                $(this).parent().append("");
            });
            var r = $(this).serialize();
            $.post($(this).attr("action"), r, function() {
                $("form#form").slideUp("fast", function() {
                    $(this).before('<div class="success">Your email was sent successfully.</div>');
                    $(".done-wrapper").toggleClass("hidden");
                });
            });
        }

        $('.label-wrap ul').find('.'+btn_class[0]).toggleClass("hide-me added haken");
        $('#form')[0].reset();

        return !1;

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the blank-page issue:
You're just processing, not outputting anything. You could simply post a redirect-header at the end - possibly according to errors occuring or not.

```
// 307 Temporary Redirect
header("Location: /foo.php",TRUE,307);
```

..or just output stuff after processing. A good practice might be to keep processing and the form-display in one file - then you could pre-populate the form with the fields that did not produce errors and mark those that failed so the user can try again.

Regarding the checkbox-group issue:

```
echo implode( ", ", $_POST['checkbox-group'] );
```

to prove to yourself you actually got something passed along:

```
header("Content-type:text/plain;charset=utf-8");
echo print_r($_POST,TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Right now, I am repeatingly slapping against my head. There was an undefinded class which caused an error. Now it is showing my "thank you message" and it functions well.

@flowtron
I am not really into php, where to put your code?

Comment: you could simply echo printr($_POST,TRUE) to see what your form passed on .. the implode of the array worked well for me. Of course, if the array is empty the resulting string will be too.

Comment: Hm, that might be a stupid question for you, but I really don't know how to echo printr() in this php-file. Could you please provide me with information about how to implement your snippet? I pasted it into several positions, nothing helped. The Checkboxes are 'checked', so I think the array is not empty. I think it is just not properly read in the php-file...

Comment: heh. sorry. typo-ed in my comment and I couldn't edit it - but I edited my answer. HTH.

Comment: I am not getting it.
Ok, I put your code print_r($_POST); and echo implode( ", ", $_POST['checkbox-group'] ); right above the first if statement. If I now go to the adress of www. ... /contact.php it gives me this:

Array ( )
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/netsh103275/html/Projektseiten/expo/contact.php on line 21

I don't know what this is...

Comment: mmmh. that seems to suggest you didn't POST anything via the form - hence the empty array output; which then leads to the key "checkbox-group" from that (empty) array not returning an array as is expected as 2nd argument for the implode-function. Maybe 1st figure it out w/o the jquery serialize/post stuff! Since you return "!1" (aka "false") the submit should actually fail - meaning not load a new page. Maybe place attribute "onsubmit='process(this); return false'" in form-tag, where the process-function then is what you currently have in the $('form#form').submit( __here__ ).